# XMLHttpRequest not working in IE9

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, xdomainrequest, typescript-declarations

I do ajax request from my "mydomain" to "anotherdomain" to get some information, i used XMLHttpRequest method in my Angular 4 application, this works fine in all browsers chrome, IE10, IE 11 except IE9.
 The problem is XMLHttpRequest method is not supported by IE9,  i tried to use XDomainRequest which is not defined in Typescript. 
 So i extended the Window interface from lib.d.ts as like specified in this link https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html.
My question is how do i include this window file in my AppModule and use XDomainRequest to make ajax request.

Note: My request domain is already CORS enabled

Answer (score 0):

Angular itself is compatible down to IE9, so I think you can solve your problem by simply using the HttpClient from Angular.

Edit:

An Example from the official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: A suggestion for you as a SO newcomer: maybe you can share some resource (documentation) or code sample to make this a more valuable answer.